# Android List Activity with dynamically loaded images form the web in android

Tags: android

I give description of My project

In my project In the first section i have parsed the xml data of Video categories and image url links from My web service.I have parsed that data and receive that data in `ArrayList` in My main activity.The first `ArrayList` is the list of video categories and the second `ArrayList` is the the list of video image urls and i have to display `ArrayList` of image urls as `ImageView` in `ListView` ,i have no idea for that,please give me some solution.

Comment: Try my sample http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012

Comment: thanx fedor for ur reply but it is too complex to understand

Comment: I'm afraid it can't be done easier. You can just reuse my ImageLoader class without understanding everything inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to handle something else than an Array of String displayed as TextView in a ListView, you need to write your own Custom Adapter (so Android knows how to display those items)

Here is an example:

Your Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity{
    private ArrayList<URL> MY_DATA;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sets the View of the Activity
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);
        ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, MY_DATA);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Your Activity's Layout (my_activity.xml here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myList"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
/>
```

And your custom Adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<URL> data;

    public EventAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<URL> data){
    // Caches the LayoutInflater for quicker use
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    // Sets the events data
    this.data= data;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }

    public URL getItem(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
        return this.data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException{
        if(position < getCount() && position >= 0 ){
            return position;
        }
    }

    public int getViewTypeCount(){
        return 1;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        URL myUrl = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(); // Use a ViewHolder to save your ImageView, in order not to have to do an expensive findViewById for each iteration

        // DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH YOUR URL (Start a new activity to download image?)

        if(convertView == null){ // If the View is not cached
        // Inflates the Common View from XML file
        convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.id.my_row_layout, null);
            holder.myImageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myRowImageView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.myImageView.setImageBitmap(MY_BITMAP_I_JUST_DOWNLOADED);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView myImageView;
    }
}
```

And finally your row's layout (my_row_layout.xml here):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/myRowImageView"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
/>
```